# trigger javascript function based on python variable value

Tags: javascript, python, html

The following 2 js functions can toggle a button to and from the disabled class. I want the disabled state to depend on the global variable `filelength` in the python code but cannot think of a simple way to do so. The only way I can think of is to have 2 identical but separate templates, one with the button disabled and one with it enabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
     function enableButton(button){
     document.getElementById(button).removeAttribute('class');
         document.getElementById(button).setAttribute("class", "button");
     }
     function disableButton(button){
         document.getElementById(button).setAttribute("class", "disabled");
     }
   </script>
```

I intended to use the functions for the following `index.html` template element.

```
<button id="Test" class="button disabled" >
Test
</button>
```

The intended toggling would produce the following `alt.html` template element which elides the "disabled".

```
<button id="Test" class="button" >
Test
</button>
```

It seems silly to require 2 separate templates (index.html and alt.html) to accomplish this toggle, but I cannot think of an alternative that permits me to just alter `index.html`. Initially I thought jinja2 would provide the functionality needed, but that does not seem correct.

How can I accomplish this without a second template using python and GAE?

For more completeness, below I show the relevant state of my python application next.

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2
import urllib

filelength = 0

class MainPage(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
    global filelength
    logging.info("text length in Main get: %s " % filelength)
    template_values = {'filelength':filelength}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):
    global filelength
    url = self.request.get('URL', None)
    text = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    logging.info("text length in Main post: %s " % len(text))
    filelength = len(text)
    if filelength > 0:
        return webapp2.redirect('/alt')
    else:
        return webapp2.redirect('/')

class AltMainPage(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
    global filelength
    logging.info("text length in Alt get: %s " % filelength)
    template_values = {'filelength':filelength}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('alt.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):
    global filelength
    url = self.request.get('URL', None)
    text = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    logging.info("text length in Alt post: %s " % len(text))
    if filelength > 0:
        return webapp2.redirect('/alt')
    else:
        return webapp2.redirect('/')
    return webapp2.redirect('/')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage), 
        ('/alt', AltMainPage), 
        ],
        debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template `index.html` simply use jinja2 to define the class attribute like this where the value of `buttonclass` is defined as either `button` or `button disabled` in python using the "if ... else" construct.

```
<button id="Test" class="{{ buttonclass }} " >
Test
</button>
```